# How to allocate tickets

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have two files :

1. Category:

```
Category_File = data.frame(c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","D","D")) 
colnames(Category_File)= c("Category")
```

2. Agent:

```
Agent_File = data.frame(c("A","A","B","B","C"),c("X","Y","X","Z","Y"),c(2,2,2,1,2))
colnames(Agent_File) = c("Category","Agent","Tickets")
```

I need to allocate agents according to their category count.

Desired Output:

```
outputfile = data.frame(c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","D","D"),c("X","X","Y","Y","NA","X","X","Z","Z","Y","NA","NA"))
colnames(outputfile) = c("Category","Agent")
```

Thanks

Comment: The desired output shown by you gives an error. Can you correct that?

Comment: corrected pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets exactly your desired output.

The only possible explanation I see behind your NAs is that you're keeping track of the row id of `Agent_File`. Therefore, first of all I set as explicit those ids.

Then I just join the two dataframes.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
af <- uncount(Agent_File, Tickets) %>% group_by(Category) %>% mutate(id = row_number()) %>% ungroup()
cf <- Category_File %>% group_by(Category) %>% mutate(id = row_number()) %>% ungroup()

left_join(cf, af, by = c("id", "Category")) %>% select(-id)

#> # A tibble: 12 x 2
#>    Category Agent
#>    <chr>    <chr>
#>  1 A        X    
#>  2 A        X    
#>  3 A        Y    
#>  4 A        Y    
#>  5 A        NA   
#>  6 B        X    
#>  7 B        X    
#>  8 B        Z    
#>  9 C        Y    
#> 10 C        Y    
#> 11 D        NA   
#> 12 D        NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
Agent_File %>% uncount(Tickets)
    Category Agent
1          A     X
1.1        A     X
2          A     Y
2.1        A     Y
3          B     X
3.1        B     X
4          B     Z
5          C     Y
5.1        C     Y
```

You can reset the index by:

```
output <- Agent_File %>% uncount(Tickets)
row.names(output) <- NULL
output
  Category Agent
1        A     X
2        A     X
3        A     Y
4        A     Y
5        B     X
6        B     X
7        B     Z
8        C     Y
9        C     Y
```

Comment: Category_File = data.frame(c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","D","D","A")) We need to add "NA" for "D" "D" and "A" since we dont have enough agents

Comment: @KalyanPavan, can you updated the question? I went by your data and your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can count `extra_rows` that you need to add.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Category_File %>%
  count(Category) %>%
  left_join(Agent_File, by = 'Category') %>%
  group_by(Category) %>%
  summarise(n = first(n) - sum(Tickets, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  uncount(n) -> extra_rows


Agent_File %>%
  uncount(Tickets) %>%
  bind_rows(extra_rows) %>%
  arrange(Category) -> result
rownames(result) <- NULL

result
#   Category Agent
#1         A     X
#2         A     X
#3         A     Y
#4         A     Y
#5         A  <NA>
#6         B     X
#7         B     X
#8         B     Z
#9         C     Y
#10        C     Y
#11        D  <NA>
#12        D  <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am adding a few lines of code in Karthik's solution proposed, as follows

```
#Create a dummy column in category file
Category_File <- Category_File %>% 
  group_by(Category) %>% 
  mutate(rowid = paste(Category, row_number()))

Agent_File %>% uncount(Tickets) %>% 
  group_by(Category) %>%
  mutate(rowid = paste(Category, row_number())) %>%
  right_join(Category_File, by = c("rowid"="rowid")) %>%
  arrange(rowid) %>%
  select(Category = Category.y, Agent)

# A tibble: 12 x 2
   Category Agent
   <chr>    <chr>
 1 A        X    
 2 A        X    
 3 A        Y    
 4 A        Y    
 5 A        NA   
 6 B        X    
 7 B        X    
 8 B        Z    
 9 C        Y    
10 C        Y    
11 D        NA   
12 D        NA
```